# Partial derivatives question help?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I have to find $∂z/∂u$ if $$z=\arctan(x/y), x=4\sin u,y=e^v$$
Can I find it directly by replacing x and y in $$z=\arctan[(4\sin u)/(e^v)]$$ Now I have to find $$∂z/∂u={1/[1+ 4\sin^2u/e^{2v}]}[(4\sin u)/(e^v)]'$$
..is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Since you need $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}$, we need to find $\partial z$ with respect to $u$. *So yes, you are correct.*

$v$ in this case would be a constant. So for $\left(\dfrac{4\sin u}{e^v}\right)'$, we differentiate with respect to $u$: That means $$\left(\dfrac{4\sin u}{e^v}\right)' = \dfrac{4\cos u}{e^v}$$

Be careful, however, if/when $v$ is defined as a function of $u$.

Comment: Great advice as usual +1

Comment: Thanks...I've put a lot of time today into reviewing prospective solutions. Most have been quite on target!